# How to programmatically receive input from UIButton in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, programmatically-created

I'm new to `Swift`. I managed to build an app which almost works, but I cannot get the last steps right. I would appreciate any help!

I wrote a code which displays a user-defined number of `UILabel`s. In those labels, the contents of a `[String]` is displayed. Under the labels, there is the same number of `UITextField`s. The user should fill out these text fields, press the button and then see if what he filled out matches the labels.

All the labels, the text fields, and the button are made completely programmatically, so without using the storyboard. In the `viewDidLoad` there is all the code and this line:

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Right under `viewDidLoad` there is this function which I found on this forum and I changed it a bit:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) -> [String] {
    var a = 0
    var userInput: [String] = Array()
    while a < 4 {
        if let myTextField = self.view.viewWithTag(a) as? UITextField {
            let tekstInput = myTextField.text
            userInput.insert(tekstInput!, at:a-1)
        }
        a = a + 1
    }
    return userInput
}
```

My problems:

The `while`-loop in the function shouldn't have 4 as the maximum, but a user-defined variable. But if I try to change function so that it expects that variable as an input, I get error messages in the `myButton.addTarget` line.

How do I read out the return in the viewdidload to add there the code to compare the user input with the original `[String]`?

Comment: How exactly the user does define the number of labels?

Comment: you can choose to store the user-defined number in the class attribute as a Int and then access it in buttonAction. Technically, you cannot add anyother input variable into the buttonAction function other than the button itself.

Comment: Thank you Deepika, this worked! I made a separate class with a code I found here (and don't understand fully) but it works like a charm. I can use this to access the Int in the button function and also to get the other variables from the viewdidload-section to check the answer.

Comment: After that, I'm stuck again, but I guess it's best to open a new question about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the source of the user-defined input if you want to answer your question.

For instance, if you are willing to add an extra `UITextField` to retrieve your user input, then all you have to do is extract the value from that text field within your `buttonAction(sender:)` method and use it there. This translates roughly to the following

```
@objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var a = 0
    var userInput: [String] = Array()

    guard let upperLimit = self.userInputTextField.text as? Int else {
        return
    }

    while a < upperLimit {
        if let myTextField = self.view.viewWithTag(a) as? UITextField {
            let tekstInput = myTextField.text
            userInput.insert(tekstInput!, at: a-1)
        }
        a = a + 1
    }

}
```

Note that `self.userInputTextField` is the extra text field you should add in order to retrieve your user-defined input.

Comment: A button action can't have a return value.

Comment: Updated my answer @rmaddy. Well noticed mate.

Comment: Thank you Jad for the answer. I should have been more clear about the user-defined input, it actually happened on another viewController, so I'm not sure if your code would work in this case. But for sure it gives me ideas for the future!

Comment: No worries @Emile! What you can do in that case is create a protocol to pass the parameter from one view controller to another. [This article](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) explains the concept I am talking about quite well.